# Remove require statement from JavaScript files made in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm developing a website and I am using TypeScript.

I use the `tsc` compiler and all my JavaScript compiles correctly, but if I use an `import` statement in my TypeScript, then it compiles into the JavaScript files as a `require` statement which is not usable in the web.

I am aware I can use something like `browserify` to fix this issue, but that includes the code of other JavaScript files when it see's a `require` statement.
I'd prefer to just include each JavaScript file in my HTML with `<script src="..."></script>`.

---

How can I prevent TypeScript from generating `require` statements in the compiled JavaScript code?

---

Here are the contents of my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./typescript/compiled",
        "removeComments": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        //"noEmit": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./typescript/**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

---

**main.ts**

```
import { Helper } from "./helper";

var helper = new Helper();
```

**helper.ts**

```
export class Helper {
    // ...
}
```

**main.js**

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const helper_1 = require("./helper");
var helper = new helper_1.Helper();
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

Comment: Can you post your tsconfig file?

Comment: I think your target should be ES5. Can you try this, if that can solve your issue?

Comment: @VinodBhavnani I just tried, the `require` statement remains.

Comment: try "target: "es5" and "module": "ES2015"

Comment: @Crappy that removed the `require` statement, but replaced it with a regular TypeScript `import {  } from "./helper"` statement which wouldn't work on a website.

Comment: @Acidic require is used by typescript to load modules, also called as npm packages that usually sit in your node_modules. If you are importing something, try converting that import into a module.

Comment: Whatever file you are importing, needs to be declared as a module. That module needs to have a logger interface, and a createlogger method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using modules in your javascript application. You don't even use import in your typescript file. Because using import mean you imports that file into your code.

If you want to have javascript file separately, use

```
/// <reference path=".. definition you want to refer ..." />
```

instead.

**UPDATED**

Since TypeScript 1.5 if you have your files in

```
"include": [
        "./typescript/**/*.ts"
    ]
```

You don't have to do `reference ...` any more.

Comment: Updated answer, tested.